# calculating the difference of the same measure with a 'different definition' in MDX

Tags: mysql, mdx, olap

I want to calculate the difference of the same measure but with a 'different definition' 
This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Births] AS 
'[Measures].[type], [dimType].[TypeL].[Births]' 
 MEMBER [Measures].[Deaths] AS 
'[Measures].[type], [dimType].[TypeL].[Deaths]' 
 MEMBER [Measures].[Population_Growth] AS 
'[Measures].[Births] - [Measures].[Deaths]' 
 SELECT [Measures].[Population_Growth] ON COLUMNS, 
 [dimTime].[year] ON ROWS FROM [Population]
```

When running this query I get Population_Growth = 0 for every year.
I am new to MDX and I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. In MDX you've evaluate a tuple. If you've a single member you do not need the brackets but you need them if you've more than one. Can you try

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Births] AS ([Measures].[type], [dimType].[TypeL].[Births]) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Deaths] AS ([Measures].[type], [dimType].[TypeL].[Deaths]) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Population_Growth] AS [Measures].[Births] - [Measures].[Deaths]
SELECT
 [Measures].[Population_Growth] ON COLUMNS, 
 [dimTime].[year] ON ROWS 
FROM [Population]
```

If this doesn't work, it might be the [type] measure :

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Births] AS ([Measures].defaultmember, [dimType].[TypeL].[Births]) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Deaths] AS ([Measures].defaultmember, [dimType].[TypeL].[Deaths]) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Population_Growth] AS [Measures].[Births] - [Measures].[Deaths]
SELECT
 [Measures].[Population_Growth] ON COLUMNS, 
 [dimTime].[year] ON ROWS 
FROM [Population]
```

if this doesn't work, we can check if the member [dimType].[TypeL].[Births] is fine.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Population_Growth] AS [dimType].[TypeL].[Births].name
SELECT
 [Measures].[Population_Growth] ON COLUMNS, 
 [dimTime].[year] ON ROWS 
FROM [Population]
```

That should return 'Births'